# Session Ends Automatically

Tags: asp.net, session, iis-7, application-pool, sessionend

**About Application:**
I build an application in .NET which I have installed on 5 sub domains. for example 
client1.mydomain.com, client2.mydomain.com . Initially I uploaded this application on a shared server.

**Issues:** I found, sometime user session end without any reason. I try to figure it out.  Support team told me that I can use maximum of 150 MB in pool. This application is using almost 70-80 MB, so I though with 5 sub domains its actually using 70*5 = 350 MB, and that's why poll is getting reset/recycling & session ends automatically.
I shifted my app on VPS.  Configuration is 2GB ram, 40GB space, Windows 2008 r2, IIS 7.5. But issues is still same.

I found lots of suggestion, but they looks to me very experimental

**My Thoughts and Query:** I guess I need to set Maximum pool size. if I am correct, I can set pool size through "Memory Based Maximums", but question is, if its uncheck what is the maximum pool size by default. and to Maximized pool size what value I can set ?

Can anyone suggest me what to check and how can I resolve this issues ?

Thanks

Comment: have you got any solution for the same?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this article.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc745955.aspx

There is an **idleTimeout** for Application Pools to Recycle.

By default it will be 5 min and you can change to any higher values [20 min preferred max].

iis manager -> Application Pools -> Select your app pool -> Advance Settings - IdleTimeout

Comment: I believe 5 or 20min will not make any difference to this issues. For example let say I set 20 min, now it will recycle at 10:20 am, a user has logged in at 10:18 so after 2 mins his session will end .. am I right ?

Comment: no, idleTimeout is the time between two server pings. if you ping [let say login] at 10.18 it will wait for 20 min for next ping.  also you could increase the "sessiontimeout" too in the web.config file.

Comment: Oh! Thanks a new thing for me.. let me try this and I will get back to you.